# Apache www to non-www redirect on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-web-services, 301-redirect, elastic-beanstalk

I've recently moved a simple PHP site to Elastic Beanstalk but am finding it difficult to redirect the `www.example.com` to `example.com`. It's not https which [most of the suggestions I have found are related to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411833/redirect-all-www-and-http-non-www-https-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-with-load).

This is what I have:

Route53:

```
A      example.com      example.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com (Alias)
CNAME  www.example.com  example.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

And in my `.htaccess` file I have the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:PROTO}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

When visiting `example.com` everything is fine but visiting `www.example.com` gives me a redirect loop:

`http://www.example.com/var/www/html/://example.com/var/www/html/://example.com`

Is this the best way to redirect on AWS?

**EDIT**

I have now also tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://%2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

and while `www.example.com` does redirect to `example.com`, it now has the redirect loop (althought without the server path in the address bar).

Comment: What is this `%{ENV:PROTO}` for? It does not look appropriate here.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's straight out of the HTML5 Boilerplate .htaccess file which worked fine for most of my projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a solution to your `.htaccess` problem, but an easy redirect solution is to redirect using an S3 bucket.

1. Setup an S3 bucket for `www.example.com` and set it up for website redirection to `example.com`
2. Set the record set for `www.example.com` in Route 53 as an ALIAS for this bucket.

This way, when your user goes to `www.example,com`, they will hit the bucket and that will redirect them to `example.com`, which will then go to your server.

Comment: Hmm... this is an interesting solution. Do you know if there are any performance implications of doing it this way? I've voted this up as it certainly works.

Comment: Amazon S3 is pretty fast and designed to scale. Many static websites use S3 exclusively and I use it for production redirection (from example.com to www.example.com). I am not aware of any performance concerns of using it. If performance is a major concern from all parts of the world, you could front this bucket with CloudFront which would cache the results for faster redirects.

Comment: Also, it lessens the load on your own server since your server will never see the redirect requests.

Comment: It seems pretty fast and I use the same redirection for static sites so it will work just fine. This seems like the best solution.

Comment: This just adds latency to the requests. Generally adding another service between what you already have will impact performance.

Comment: @Victor the OP asked how to perform a redirect, which by it's own nature is an HTTP call then **another** HTTP call. There's no service "in between" anything.

Comment: @MattHouser I am generally against this specific procedure. Could you please add a solution involving nothing but the `.ebextensions` and an Apache configuration file? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1100363/1673776) answer on StackOverflow and I failing to incorporate it in a `.conf` file via and `.ebextensions` configuration.

Comment: @Victor I do not recommend that as a solution to this problem. I have already provided the solution I recommend. If you want an answer to your question, you can ask it directly as a new ServerFault question and wait for an answer.